# How do I import all MDC packages individually rather than as material-components-web?

Tags: sass, mdc, material-components-web

I am at the optimisation stage and have, up to this point, been importing `material-components-web`. Now, I want to import the entire library as separate packages so that I can comment out the modules that I'm not using. So, I read the docs and added the JavaScript imports and initialisations and the SASS `@use`s and `@include`s for every package and renamed duplicate `style` namespaces and commented out the duplicate `@use` references. However, I am fighting with an undefined mixin.

```
Error
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
77 │ @include icon-button.core-styles; // Undefined mixin
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  stdin 77:1  root stylesheet
```

[Here is a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-worker-t5t2p?file=/src/styles.scss) with just the JS imports and SCSS `@use` and `@include` statements demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `@use '@material/icon-button'` with `@use '@material/icon-button/icon-button'`. Also you need to add package `@material/icon-button`. Currently package structure is not consistent across the package set. I guess MDC team is experimenting with its structure.

Also remove `@use '@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button';`. These **/mdc-<package-name>.scss** or **/styles.scss** files are needed just for convenience in case you want to include CSS right away, without additional `@include <package-name>.core-styles` call.

Comment: Hi Konstantin. Sorry for the late thank you and reply. When you say "Also you need to add package @material/icon-button.", is this as an import, use or include?

Comment: @OinkQuack as far as I remember I was talking about package.json. I guess in your codesandbox example this package wasn't included in package.json. Probably it was updated since, because now it does include @material/icon-button package.

Comment: @OinkQuack to sum up, there are multiple ways to include component styles into your CSS: 1) `@use '@material/icon-button/mdc-icon-button';` - this one calls `@include icon-button.core-styles` for you, so no additional call is needed, otherwise styles will be duplicated. 2) `@use '@material/icon-button/icon-button'` and then later `@include icon-button.core-styles`